# Es posible hacer una animación en un display?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy practicando código en una web personal, y estaba haciendo un login dependiendo si eres administrador o usuario invitado.
La cosa es que cuando le doy al botón de guest mode, oculto el div con un display none.
Sería posible pasar de uno a otro con algun tipo de animación por ejemplo fade, para que sea más suave, y no sea tan brusco el cambio ?

```js
function abrirInvitado() {
    document.getElementById("vistaInvitado").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("vistaAdministrador").style.display = "none";
}

function abrirAdministrador() {
    document.getElementById("vistaInvitado").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("vistaAdministrador").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* user-select: none; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  background: #dde1e7;
}

.contenido {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.invitado {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.content{
  width: 330px;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 7px #ffffff73,
               2px 2px 5px rgba(94,104,121,0.288);
}
.content .text{
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: #595959;
}
.field{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.field:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.field input{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 45px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  color: #595959;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
              inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
.field input:focus{
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #BABECC,
              inset -1px -1px 2px #ffffff73;
}
.field span{
  position: absolute;
  color: #595959;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.field label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 45px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #666666;
}
.field input:valid ~ label{
  opacity: 0;
}
.forgot-pass{
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;
}
.forgot-pass a{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forgot-pass:hover a{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button{
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #595959;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
             -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
button:focus{
  color: #3498db;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
             inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
.sign-up{
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sign-up a{
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sign-up a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.volver-atras {
  padding-left: 23px;
  display: flex;
  width: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>PortFolio</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="contenido">
    <div id="vistaAdministrador" class="content" >
      <div class="text">Acceso Privado</div>
        <form action="#">
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text" required>
            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            <label>Usuario</label>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="password" required>
            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            <label>Contraseña</label>
          </div>
          <div class="forgot-pass">
            <button>Iniciar Sesion</button>
            <div class="sign-up"> ¿Quieres ver la web?
            <a onclick="abrirInvitado()" title="Modo Invitado" style="cursor: pointer;">Guest Mode</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="vistaInvitado" class="invitado" style = "display: none">
        <div class="content">
        <div class="text">Modo Invitado</div>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="field">
                    <input id="usuario" type="text" required>
                    <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                    <label>Nombre de Usuario</label>
                </div>
            <button>Iniciar Sesion</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    <button class="volver-atras" onclick="abrirAdministrador()">
      <i data-feather="corner-up-left"></i>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  feather.replace();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: [`display` no es una propiedad animable.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#formal_definition)

Comment: y como puedo animarlo ? para que haga un face

Comment: Tu pregunta ya fue marcada como duplicada de otra. _Revisa la otra pregunta_.